# Jquery plugin masongram problem of limititation

Tags: jquery, github, instagram, instagram-api

hi I found the Jquery plugin masongram from GitHub, all works perfectly when I'm using it, but can someone can explain me why when I add my access token I can see only 20 images contrary to when I let the original access token, I can see more than 20 images ??? all works fine with the owner's access token, there is no limit after 20 images. why he doesn't have same limit ?

here is the link of the plugin:

https://github.com/mladenplavsic/masongram

here is link of the demo with more than 20 images:

https://mladenplavsic.github.io/masongram/

Answer (score 0):

afters days of research, I let an answer if some people are in the same situation. I generate another access token with pixel union and mostly, deleted and authorized the app again with instagram and now all works fine.